# Friendly termination of gunicorn to keep open connections?

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I wish to upgrade my server and need a way to install a new flask server (wrapped with gunicorn). I need a way to start using the new code but to let existing connections finish. What is a way in which this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sending a `HUP` signal to your gunicorn process.

```
kill -HUP <pid>
```

Gunicorn should gracefully restart your application, allowing existing connections to finish. Here's the [documentation](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/signals.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I kept looking under deployment. I think I need QUIT in my case (I'm launching software from a new directory).